# Failed File.Copy attempt to FAT and FAT 32 file systems makes the target file empty

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, filesystems, fat32

If the file is located in the NTFS file system, everything seems to be fine. However, if the file is located on FAT or FAT32 file system, file's content is getting erased and it becomes a 0KB file after [File.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=net-6.0).

```
File.Copy(biggerFile, smallerFile, true);
```

The issue happens when there is no enough space on the "smallerFile"s drive and File.Copy operation fails with IOException.

Is this something that is expected, because I can't find this behavior documented anywhere?

Comment: No, that's definitely not expected behavior. After all, setting some file attributes should not shred the file, regardless of the file system in use. Does your code access the respective file in any other manner before or after it invokes File.SetAttributes that could possibly truncate/overwrite the file?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Thanks a lot. I verified with console application that this does not happen when just setting the attributes. I've edited my original post and added the exact case when this happens and is easily reproducible via console app + FAT drive which is almost out of space.

Comment: Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/backup-and-storage/fat-hpfs-and-ntfs-file-systems - "In addition, FAT supports only read-only, hidden, system, and archive file attributes.". Seems setting to Normal in FAT drive leads to unexpected results like this. However, it can't be reproduced without making the Copy operation to fail first.

Comment: The issue "sometimes" is reproducible with FileAttributes.Archive too.

Comment: Hmm, just taking pot-shots in the dark: What happens if you delay setting the attributes after the failed copy? E.g., like doing `Thread.Sleep(5000);` in the catch block before setting the attributes. Still same behavior?

Comment: See exceptions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setattributes?view=net-6.0

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Yes, it's reproducible with even 30 seconds Thread.Sleep or when running Copy and SetAttributes statements separately during my console application's 2 different runs.

Comment: @jdweng It's not throwing an exception. If it changes something, we are using .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: That's curious. What happens if you are not setting attributes in your (test) code, but after the failed copy operation set the attributes through the file properties dialog (or some file manager)?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Great catch! I've just tested it, it still becomes 0KB ))

Comment: If you can and if you have not done so already, try doing your test on another computer (or inside a virtual machine with virtual FAT/FAT32 drives) that doesn't have any 3rd-party software installed. This suggestion is basically an attempt to figure out whether the observed behavior is intrinsic to Windows itself, or whether there is possibly a 3rd-party software/driver contributing to it.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace - I was able to reproduce it on my second machine too.

Comment: Hmm. What if you were to copy back the partially copied file (without using SetAttributes and killing it) from the test drive S:? Can you actually copy it and is there data in it, or is it locked, or do you get only a 0-byte file copied despite the file size being larger than 0KB?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Yes, it seems it's just because of the Windows's cache that it still shows NOT 0KB. Seems setting attributes is not a problem, the file is already empty after failed copy attempt. I will edit the question's description now.

Comment: New screen recording - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3sdtEGoOYo

Comment: (1/2) I can't tell whether this is expected or not, but perhaps it is the byproduct of something similar as the following: If the file size of a newly created file is known beforehand, the new file can be created with disk-space being preallocated for the entire file size without having anything written to it yet. File.Copy (and the Win32 FileCopyEx it invokes) could perhaps do something like that. And perhaps it's setting up the file chache entry with the final file size (and possibly the actual FAT/32 entry too) before actually attempting to pre-allocate, with the pre-allocation then failing

Comment: (2/2) In such a situation, nothing has actually been written to the target file yet, which in some manner could explain the observed behavior. However, i am only speculating here, and i have nothing else to backup my speculation...

Comment: Yes, I am also thinking about similar scenarios. This is super bad though from the user perspective. You can simply lose your data and this is not happening on NTFS systems based on my tests. Or, perhaps, there is some other setting which controls this and I can get that only for FAT and FAT32 file systems.

Comment: It's not super bad, because you get the exception. Ignoring the exception you do at your own peril. You know that the file copy did not succeed, and if that already incurs a risk of data loss, then your or your users entire strategy about keeping important files safe is severely lacking.

Comment: I don't understand: you haven't lost anything. `File.Copy` does not delete the source file, so you can just copy again once space is freed up. It's entirely expected that the data is not committed if there is an exception, the only surprising thing is that the destination file remains at all, you would have thought it would be deleted.

Comment: @Charlieface Based on my tests, on NTFS file system the destination file is remaining intact even in case of exception. I'm not sure how it works internally. It seems to me that allocating the space in advance would be better and would prevent data loss (it could just throw exception rightaway if it would not be able to allocate the needed space).

Comment: It's probably simply a factor of buffer flushing, which for some reason is not happening on FAT. Like I said, you have an exception so the results are not guaranteed anyway.

Comment: You may consider checking that there is sufficient space to copy the file prior to attempting to copy/replace it. If there isn't enough space don't attempt to copy/replace the file, instead notify the user that there isn't enough space.

Comment: @user9938 - Yeah, that is an option, of course. However, it could be costly and most of the times meaningless when copying millions of files. I will look for workarounds since you guys helped me to confirm that this is an expected behavior.